# Как убрать в Битрикс, в конце урл страницы слеш

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет. Кто знает как убрать из урл последний слеш для текстовых страниц? В комплесных компонентах убрал.

Comment: Вопрос не полный, он касается правил формирования ЧПУ в комплексном компоненте или создания статических разделов?

Comment: создайте для этих страниц правила в `urlrewrite.php`.